# Setting the Limit For Draggable Div

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-draggable

I have a Div Which Shows on Click of Table Cell of another(TableDiv) Div.I need to set the  Boundraies (Limits) depend on the TableDiv Width and Height.My Draggable is out side of TableDiv.

```
<div class="TableDiv">
<table>
</table>
</div>
<div id="draggingDiv">
</div>
```

My Jquery  Code  as below

```
    $("#draggingDiv").draggable({reset:true});
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

Its clearly an issue with css positioning.
It would be great if u share the css styling of your divs.

But according to me adding this to your style sheet would solve the problem

```
position:absolute;
width : 100%;
height : 100%;
```

% Sizing fixes the div to 100% of its parent div.
Same thing could be applicable to draggable element too.